# Creating subsections in pkgdown function reference page (R)

Tags: r, package, code-documentation, pkgdown

How is it possible to create not only first-level but also second-level headers in function reference page of R package documentation created with `pkgdown`?
Can I do this by modifying the `_pkgdown.yml` file?

**More details**:

An example of an R package (as a ZIP file) is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/example-of-package--for-pkgdown).
It contains 3 "hello" and 1 "other" function. I want two `<H1>` level (first-level) section "Hello" and "Other" and also "Hello" functions should be split into 2 subsections (level `<H2>`) an in the last print-screen.

The project contains `_pkgdown.yml` file with these settings that control the appearance of the reference page, and maybe it's possible to tweak this code to get the desired results?:

```
destination: docs

reference:
# All 3 Hello function should be in a super section A, e.g., level <H1>
  - title: "Hello A functions" # This should be subsection A-1, e.g., level <H2>
    contents:
    - hello-a1
    - hello-a2
  - title: "Hello B functions"  # This should be subsection A-2, e.g., level <H2>
    contents:
    - hello-b1
# This should be in super section B, e.g., level <H1>
  - title: "Other functions"
    contents:
    - other
```

The output of the reference page **looks like this** one:
[image]

The type of output I **expect** should be similar to:

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I updated the question. Is it more clear now @MrFlick?